# How to fix markdown that renders fine in edit mode

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504141/950099) and noticed its main code block was rendering a bit funny. I assumed this was something wrong with the answer I could edit to fix up.

[image: normal view]

However after clicking Edit, it looks fine in the editor preview without any changes.

[image: edit view]

What's going on here and what should I do?

Comment: It renders correctly when intending with four spaces. No clue though why it doesn't with fences.

Comment: That answer was posted before code fences were added (in [early 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000)), so likely the rendered output was simply cached, which would explain why it worked in the preview.

Comment: @TiiJ7 Yep, seems to be the case. I re-edited it and it renders correctly with fences now.